# move the icon to the absolute position of the element that was hovered or clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$('.class1').on('mouseenter', function () {

var top_offset = $(this).position().top;
var left_offset = $(this).position().left;

  $('.icon').prependTo($(this)).css({
     position: "absolute",
     top: top_offset,
     left: left_offset
  });
});
```

On mouse enter or hover I get the position of that element and I have an icon that I want to move it to that position, But I want to do it with animation so the user sees it.HOW CAN I DO IT?

Comment: what's the position of `.icon` initialy. try using `.animate()` function on `.icon` element. See more here (http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: the positions will store in "var top_offset" and "left_offset"

Comment: That's the last position or the position when the animation ends right?

Comment: no, i have two icons, the first one is the hovered one, second is the icon that I want to animate it to the hovered icon position, both have different positions

Comment: See this example(https://jsfiddle.net/j6supy30/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.class1').on('mouseenter', function () {

var top_offset = $(this).position().top;
var left_offset = $(this).position().left;
var class1 = this

$('#icon').css('position', 'relative').animate({

    top: top_offset,
    left: left_offset
}, 1000, function () { $(this).prependTo($(class1)) });
```

});

you have to use jQuery animate. this is very simple. just set your duration and what you want in end of execution. the CSS is up to you and up to your html design.